# Weird Delimiter

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, delimiter

In Python, I am trying to parse a file and separate values, however, I am working with a weird delimiter.  Could anyone help out?  Thanks!

The lines in the file I am parsing appear similarly as:

```
john-burk AL
john-smith    CA
john-joe    FL
john-john  TX
```

Current code:

```
with open('info.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        try:
            name, state = line.split(<do not know what to use>)
        except Exception as e:
            print "[-] Error parsing data " + str(e)
```

Expected output:

```
name = "john-burk"
state = "AL"
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Looks like a `'\t'` (tab) character to me.

Comment: Oh, sorry, should have clarified that a little better.  Expected out should be `name="john-burk", state="AL"`

Comment: @Gall will using tab as my delimiter cover the single spaces though?

Comment: @SakamakiIzayoi Will the name column have any whitespace characters?

Comment: @SakamakiIzayoi No, but you should check if this is actually a space and not a 'variable-length space' due to the tab by visualizing all characters in a text editor (for example).

Comment: @sakamiIzayoi sometimes a tab (`\t`) will look like a single space character, it's worth trying out to see what happens.

Comment: @Gall I have my tab space set to 1 in Sublime Text, so I am guessing they were written into the file with random spaces separating them (don't know how it happened)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) documentation,

> `str.split([sep[, maxsplit]])`
>   **If *sep* is not specified** or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: **runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator**, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

So, you can simply do

```
name, state = line.split()
print name, state
```

since we havn't specified the delimiter, Python will split based on the any number of consecutive whitespace characters as the delimiter. So, your data can be split into `name` and `state`

**Note:** This will not work if the `name` has any whitespace characters.

Comment: This is the answer I am looking for.  Cannot believe I was overthinking it.  I'll select this as the answer when it allows me to.  Thanks!